# What does this code in HTACCESS say

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I' am just a beginner trying to learn about HTACCESS but can't seem to find anything on Google that will explain what this code below means. I know it for making pretty URL's but what is the long description of it. Please can someone professional or experts can guide me in explaining this. Thanks!

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at it line by line

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
```

This says that whatever is between the tags should only be read if, and only if, mod_rewrite is installed and enabled on the target server.

```
RewriteEngine On
```

This turns the RewriteEngine on. Without it, no RewriteRules take effect. ([docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteengine))

```
RewriteBase /
```

RewriteBase is used when redirecting a request. As far as I am aware, it can never hurt to set it, even though sometimes it goes right automatically. ([docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase))

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
```

This is the first RewriteRule. If a request is done to `http://example.com/index.php` (with or without a query string), the url is not rewritten. The `[L]` denotes that if this rule matches, it is the last rule that will be matched during this 'pass' through the file. Because the url is not rewritten, no further 'passes' through the `.htaccess` file are done.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

If the previous rule didn't match, it will try to match this rule. This rule matches any url of at least 1 character. A request to `http://example.com` would not match this rule. If the first part of the RewriteRule matches, it will check the conditions. The first condition checks if the file that is requested (`%{REQUEST_FILENAME}`) is not an existing file (`!-f`). `-f` means "is an existing file" and the prefix `!` negates that. The second condition is similar, but tests if the requested file is not an existing directory. If both conditions are true, the request will be internally rewritten to `index.php`. The `[L]` flag will stop rewriting for this pass, and during the next pass the first rule will match, and stop rewriting altogether.

See [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for more information about what is possible with `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule`.

Comment: Excellent, very clear explanation. Thanks for the reference links too. Cheers!